# Fastlane plugins not installed

Tags: github-actions, fastlane

I am using `fastlane` during my github actions builds.
But since I added a new plugin, I started receiving an error:

```
It seems like you wanted to load some plugins, however they couldn't be loaded
```

This is my `Pluginfile`:

```
# Autogenerated by fastlane
#
# Ensure this file is checked in to source control!

#gem 'fastlane-plugin-json'
```

Here is part of the github workflow:

```
 runs-on: ubuntu-latest

   steps:
      ....

      - name: Setup Ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: '2.6'
          bundler-cache: true

      - name: Setup Fastlane
        working-directory: ./application
        run: bundle install

      - name: Build Android version
        timeout-minutes: 10
        working-directory: ./application
        run: bundle exec fastlane build platform:android
```

when it comes to the usage of the `json` plugin, I receive another error:

```
Could not find action, lane or variable 'read_json'.
```

which just confirms that plugins were not loaded correctly

Any ideas on how this can be fixed? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have commented out the line `#gem 'fastlane-plugin-json'` in your Pluginfile. Try removing the `#` character from the start of that line.